# Why does recomposition occur before navigation?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

```
sample1Binding.composeView.setContent {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("before nav") }
    Button(onClick = {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_sample1_to_sample2)
        text = "after nav"
    }) {
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

I have a `fragment` with a `Button` `composable` in it. on clicking the `button`, a `navigation` should occur then the value of `text` should change. What actually happens is that `text` visibly changes, then navigation occurs.

Why does this happen and is there a way around this?